# Jest failing to test component that imports FontAwesomeIcon

Tags: react-native, font-awesome-5

I am trying to test a simple functional react-native component using Jest and react-test-renderer. After importing the FontAwesomeIcon component into my component, my tests are failing with the following:

```
FAIL  src/BudgetLog/components/TransactionList/__tests__/TransactionList.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/alexlauni/Code/flex-monet/node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { default as FontAwesomeIcon } from './dist/components/FontAwesomeIcon'
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 | import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
    | ^
  4 | import { faCommentAlt as commentIcon } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
  5 |
  6 | const TransactionListItem = ({ created_at, created_by, amount }) => {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/BudgetLog/components/TransactionList/TransactionListItem.js:3:1)
```

What's the right solution to fix this for my project? Likely more components are going to use FontAwesome icons, so I'm looking for a solution that will be mostly transparent in the future.

I see that jest talks about "transforms", but I don't understand what it's talking about, and I found the documentation a bit dense. I think I could possibly mock FontAwesomeIcon component, but I'm concerned I'd have to explicitly mock every single icon I use then, which seems overly burdensome. Is there a better solution? This feels like something that just needs some configuration.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I mocked the module @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome inside of the test file and it passed!

```
jest.mock('@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome', () => ({
    FontAwesomeIcon: ''
}))
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! ^____^

Answer (score 5):

I mocked it up different. Using the Font Awesome [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react#unit-testing) I came up with this solution.

1. Create this file (I'm using TS, made it the right extension):

```js
__mocks__\@fortawesome\react-fontawesome.tsx
```

2. Paste this:

```js
import React from 'react'

export function FontAwesomeIcon({ className, children, ...props }: { className?: string, children: any }) {
    return <i className={`fa ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</i>
}
```

3. Make your tests:

```js
  test('Renders a single button with an icon', async () => {
    render(
      <ButtonBox label='label color='btn-grey' icon={['fas', 'coffee']} />
    )
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('button-icon')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!  Lots and lots of googling and this was the only thing I found that solved my problem.

Comment: When using react-native name the file `__mocks__\@fortawesome\react-native-fontawesome.tsx`